# Accessing Google Drive from a Google App Engine Python app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I have an existing Google App Engine Python app with a lot of functionality. I now want to integrate Google Drive into the app. Specifically I want my app to be able to:

1. Create an empty file in my user's Google Drive where my user can create a Google Doc.
2. Retrieve that file from Google Drive for further processing in my app.
3. Send it back to Google Drive periodically so that the user can perform further editing on it as a Google Doc.

I'd be eternally grateful if someone who knows how to do what I'm trying to do can direct me to the SPECIFIC Google webpage(s) that address my SPECIFIC requirement (not a general answer like, "See the DrEdit example"). Thanks in advance!

***Update:***

Based on the generated sample code in `drive-v2-python-appengine` per the suggestion in Answer 1, here's my program with a RequestHandler for creating an empty file:

```
import os
import webapp2

import io

from google.appengine.api import memcache

import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaIoBaseUpload
from oauth2client.appengine import oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets


decorator = oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'client_secrets.json'),
    scope=[
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    ])

http = httplib2.Http(memcache)
drive_service = build("drive", "v2", http=http)


class CreateEmptyFile(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @decorator.oauth_required
    def get(self):
        body = {
            'title': 'Sample Document',
            'description': 'A sample document',
            'mimeType': 'text/plain'
        }
        media_body = MediaIoBaseUpload(io.BytesIO(""), mimetype='text/plain', resumable=True)
        file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()
        self.redirect("/synopsis")
```

Testing is somewhat confusing, because occasionally when I've run this, including the first time, it's brought up the access request page, but most of the time it doesn't. I've used https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en to revoke access to Drive and Drive no longer shows up on the list, but I guess a time delay of an hour or more exists for carrying out the access revocation. Not sure about that, and haven't seen it documented.

In any case, if I comment-out the call to `drive_service.files().insert()`, it does not abort, and redirects to my synopsis page. I believe this means the authorization is working correctly, since that makes it like the generated sample code.

However, if I un-comment the `insert` and use `resumable=True` for the media body, I get:

```
ResumableUploadError: Failed to retrieve starting URI.
```

And if I use `resumable=False`, I get:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart&alt=json returned "Login Required">
```

So I seem to be able to get thru the OAuth 2.0 authorization, but cannot insert a file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, consider rewriting your question and remove some paragraphs which are not relevant to answer it (like the 4th and 5th). Try to be concrete, because I had to read it twice to understand what you want, and the scope of this question seems very broad.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the welcome and guidance. Hopefully my edited version is better. The scope is not intended to be broad: I simply want my app to be able to send docs back and forth to Google Drive so that users can edit the docs using the Google Docs UI, but I can also work with the docs in my app.

Comment: I like this question - where do you find "drive-v2-python-appengine"?  I can't find it online.  I don't like DrEdit because it relies on a lot of obfuscated javascript to run.  Looking for a more straightforward example.

Answer (score 1):

Please try our quickstart app at:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation

You can create a quickstart app engine app, which is useful for you to create the initial setup. For specific use-cases, please refer to the [drive API reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/).

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. I also tried DrEdit at https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python (it took me hours of working thru it to realize that it had nothing to do with my requirements). And via https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-python, I watched the video, got the app running, and studied the code, but so far have not seen how to extend that info to GAE and removing the manual processes. Getting back to the page you suggested, I get: "Invalid arguments"

Comment: I think I get "Invalid arguments" because the command should be "dev_appserver.py ." (not sure, just guessing), but that gave "ValueError('insecure string pickle',)". Per the comment's suggestion, I then tried "dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore ." That gave "socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use"

Comment: I think that's because on my Mac, Apache is already using 8080, and I don't know how to modify the sample code from your link to use 8081 instead. However, I'll look at the generated code and see if I can incorporate it into my running app. Thanks again!

Comment: OK, I ran it in my IDE (PyCharm), using `-p 8081 --use_sqlite`, and got the "Congratulations" page. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Lindsay if that was useful you should mark the answer as accepted. Read more here on why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @Lipis Ah, I didn't know how. I see it's the checkmark. Thanks.

Comment: @Lindsay Yes.. you'll have to click on it :)

Comment: @Takashi Matsuo I've unchecked Accepted again and added "Update" to my original question.

Comment: That makes the question and answer less clear for others. Can you revert the question, accept this again and open a new question?