# How to use Google Drive API from Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-drive-api

I have an app in GAE (Python 2.7), and now need access to Google Drive to display a (shared) list of folders and documents.

Searching usually results in pointers to DrEdit, including [App Engine and Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185504/app-engine-and-google-drive-api), which asks the same question but accepts an answer I don't agree with, as DrEdit is an example app for Google Drive, not GAE.

The files list from the Drive API is what I'd like to be able to use from GAE: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Comment: "DrEdit is a web application written on Google App Engine in Python".  What's wrong with it? https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454708/accessing-google-drive-from-a-google-app-engine-python-app has the comment "Thanks. I tried that. I also tried DrEdit at developers.google.com/drive/examples/python (it took me hours of working thru it to realize that it had nothing to do with my requirements)." DrEdit is an app for Google Drive, i.e. adding functionality to Google Drive. I just want to read Drive from GAE. I'll look at DrEdit again, somewhere in there is probably the info I need...

Comment: DrEdit does contain all of the necessary setup information.  However, like many sample-apps, it is pretty complex.  If someone comes across this thread, and has just the basic wiring of a Drive-Api-app, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although Google App Engine and Google Drive are both Google products, unfortunately they are not directly linked. Google Drive APIs can be accessed by the `google-api-python-client` library, which you have to install.

The process can be found at [Python Google Drive API Quickstart Guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/python), and the summarized form is as follows:

1. On Google's side: Allow Drive API Access for your GAE program

   - [Activate Drive API](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=drive). Click the **Go to credentials** button to continue...
   - **Create your consent screen:** Setup your **OAuth Consent Screen** as Google will throw weird errors if this has not been set up:

     - Click on the **OAuth Consent Screen** tab
     - Select an **Email address** and enter a **Product name**.
   - **Get credentials:**

     - Click on the **Credentials** tab
     - Select **Add credentials** and then **OAuth 2.0 client ID**. Choose your application type, and enter the relevant details. You can change them later!
     - Back on the Credentials tab, download the JSON credentials (all the way to the right in the table, the download button only appears when you hover near it). Rename it `client_secret.json` and place it in your root code directory. You will need this to request credentials from users.
2. On your side: [Download the `google-api-python-client` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-api-python-client/), unzip it in your code directory and run `python setup.py install`. This will install the library which holds many Google product's APIs.
3. Now you are ready to use the Drive API. You can test your access using the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample). Read it because it's a good guide for writing your own code! If you are accessing user data, you will need to request user credentials when they log in and most probably store them. Then, to use the API, the easiest way would be to get the `service` object:

   ```
   import httplib2
   from apiclient import discovery

   credentials = get_credentials() #Your function to request / access stored credentials
   #Authorise access to Drive using the user's credentials
   http = credentials.authorise(httplib2.Http())
   #The service object is the gateway to your API functions
   service = discovery.build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

   #Run your requests using the service object. e.g. list first 10 files:
   results = service.files().list(maxResults=10).execute()
   # ... etc ... Do something with results
   ```

Above code snippet is modified from [sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample).

The Reference API for Google Drive can be [found here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/).

The same general procedure is required to link GAE to other Google product's APIs as well e.g. Calendar. All the best writing your program!

Answer (score 1):

For future reference (this question is quite old, but it seems like [it's still an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145752442)), now the GCP IAM API has an [endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/generateAccessToken?apix_params=%7B%22name%22%3A%22projects%2F-%2FserviceAccounts%2FSERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID%40PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22scope%22%3A%5B%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive%22%5D%7D%7D) to get access tokens with arbitrary scopes. I'm understanding this question as a 2-legged OAuth flow (the app has access to its own Drive files), as opposed to a 3-legged OAuth flow (the app is requesting access to the Drive API on behalf of the customer).

That endpoint is used for [Service Account delegation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials), which is a more involved flow.

You can get the right permissions on the Service Account to generate tokens for itself with this command:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding $(gcloud config get-value project)@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --member serviceAccount:$(gcloud config get-value project)@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
```

**Example**

Once the Service Account has the right permissions, you can get a token with the right scopes by first authenticating on the CLI (this step is not required on GAE, since the default service account is already authenticated):

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key --iam-account $(gcloud config get-value project)@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
gcloud auth activate-service-account $(gcloud config get-value project)@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --key-file key
gcloud config set account $(gcloud config get-value project)@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

Then, you can make the authenticated call to the IAM API to get a token with different scopes:

```
curl -H"Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -H'content-type:application/json' https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/$(gcloud config get-value project)@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken -d"{'scope':['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']}"
```

With this token, you can directly call the Drive API for files where the default GAE service account () has access:

```
token=$(curl -H"Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -H'content-type:application/json' https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/$(gcloud config get-value project)@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken -d"{'scope':['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']}"|jq -r .accessToken)

curl -H"Authorization: Bearer $token" https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FILE_ID>
```

To finish, remember to clean up (delete the keys for this example):

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys delete $(cat key|jq -r .private_key_id) --iam-account $(cat key|jq -r .client_email) -q
gcloud auth revoke $(gcloud config get-value project)@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
rm key
```

To make the call to generate the access token from GAE, you can use the [Google Cloud Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries). For Python, you would use [google.cloud.iam_credentials_v1.IAMCredentialsClient.generate_access_token](https://googleapis.dev/python/iamcredentials/latest/gapic/v1/api.html#google.cloud.iam_credentials_v1.IAMCredentialsClient.generate_access_token).

---

To summarize:

1. Grant `iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` to the GAE default service account
2. Grant access to that account to the specific drive file
3. Generate a token with the right scopes from the IAM Credentials API ([`projects.serviceAccounts/generateAccessToken`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/generateAccessToken))
4. Make the authenticated call to the Drive API using that token

For best results, generate the token during initialization, cache it, and re-create it every hour (1 hour is the max TTL for those generated access tokens).