# Can't see Drive SDK in Google App Engine console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I've created a project and was following tutorials to enable Drive API and Drive SDK but Drive SDK isn't showing in console. Snapshot of console is added below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google API such as Google Drive, Calendar etc. in Google App Engine(GAE). Unfortunately, they are not directly linked but you can use `google-api-python-client` library (which you have to install).

You can follow the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python) to start the integration with GAE and Google APIs.

Here is the following code given in the answer from the [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524119/how-to-use-google-drive-api-from-google-app-engine?rq=1):

```
import httplib2
from apiclient import discovery

credentials = get_credentials() #Your function to request / access stored credentials
#Authorise access to Drive using the user's credentials
http = credentials.authorise(httplib2.Http())
#The service object is the gateway to your API functions
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

#Run your requests using the service object. e.g. list first 10 files:
results = service.files().list(maxResults=10).execute()
# ... etc ... Do something with results
```

Also include from the SO question is the API reference for the [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/).

I hope this helps you. :)